# código de barras no android impressora bluetooh

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, impressora, hexadecimal

Consigo imprimir qualquer coisa menos o código de barras, atualmente uso:

```
            byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
            cmd[0] = 0x1b;
            cmd[1] = 0x21;
            cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
            out.write(cmd);
            out.write("Mensagem de teste \n".getBytes());
```

A impressora é a ZJ-5802DD, já tentei vários códigos, baixei alguns manuais da linguagem:

http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf

Para imprimir o código de barras ficaria assim:

```
    String content = "1234567890";
    byte[] contents = content.getBytes();
    byte[] formats  = {(byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x49, (byte)content.length()};
    byte[] bytes    = new byte[formats.length + contents.length];
    System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length );
    System.arraycopy(contents, 0, bytes, formats.length, contents.length);
    out.write(bytes);
```

Porém não funciona, vi aqui [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057171/print-barcode-using-thermal-printer-android) onde dizem conseguir na mesma impressora, pois ela suporta, mas não postaram o código :(

Comment: Verifique se esses `SDK` ajuda:

http://www.intersite.co.th/UserFiles/files/PP5802LD-SDK-FOR-Android.rar
http://www.intersite.co.th/index.php?m=download

Comment: O link está quebrado :(